# Using a Unix Domain Socket to Control VLC

Tags: socket, vlc

I am interested in using a UNIX-Domain Socket to control VLC playback. This functionality is outlined in the [VideoLan documentation for using oldrc](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aAdvanced_Use_of_VLC/#RC_and_RTCI).

So what I need to is startup vlc with a command such as:

```
cvlc <path to media> -I oldrc --rc-unix /some/socket
```

And then I should be able to send vlc commands to `/some/socket` to control the playback.

Are there any general-purpose sockets floating around somewhere on my Kubuntu 12.10 system that I could use for this?

Comment: Clarifying this question since the "I should be able to send vlc commands to /some/socket" was vague: The magic combo for me was to execute "vlc /path/to/yourfile.mp4 -I oldrc --rc-unix /home/pi/vlcsocket" and then send commands to it with "echo "pause" | nc -U -q 1 /home/pi/vlcsocket". "-I rc" does not work, apparently. The socket is never created. Hence. "-I oldrc".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are no spare sockets just floating around, But they are easy to make, so easy that you may have done so if the directory you were creating them in existed and you had write permission. To make your example work you probably need `mkdir /some; chown vlc_user.rmt_grp /some; chmod 0775 /some`. and it is easier if the remote control and the player run as the same user.

Comment: Yes! You are right, vlc creates a socket if it doesn't exist. The trouble was that the module `rc` has been renamed to `oldrc`! That help page is out of date. Also, is it appropriate to use `netcat` to send messages to the socket after it's opened by vlc?

Comment: Wow.  I just spent over half an hour trying to figure out why none of the examples I found worked.  Then, finally, I found your comment.  Then I launched VLC with `vlc -I oldrc --rc-unix socket-name`, and voila, it works.  Using `vlc -I rc --rc-unix socket-name` doesn't give any errors, but VLC never opens the socket, so it doesn't work, for no apparent reason.

Comment: holy sheet, just been struggling with this too for about 1 hour, official wiki is so out of date....